# How to find applications which use Replay Protected Memory Block (RPMB) partition of the underlying storage device in Android Trusty?

Tags: android, drm, tee

I am trying to find a list of applications which use RPMB partition in the underlying Storage Device (eMMC/UFS/NVMe) in Android Trusty environment.

How do I go about doing this ?

Thanks